# Methods returning incorrect values?

Tags: java, methods, output

Just writing a simple program that asks the user to enter either circle, rectangle, or triangle. It then asks them for the appropriate measurements of the shape and then uses the correct method to calculate the area of this shape.
However the correct answer is only generated for the rectangle method.
The circle method always generates 0.0 no matter what input and the triangle method does not multiply by 0.5 but returns just base*height.

Made some of the suggested changes and am still having the same problems. Here is the full code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Area{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String shape = "";
    boolean notAcceptable = true;

    do {
        System.out.print("What kind of shape? ");
        shape = myScanner.next();
        if(shape.equals("circle") || shape.equals("triangle") || shape.equals("rectangle")){
            notAcceptable= false;
        }else{
            System.out.println("ERROR: Please input 'circle','rectangle' or 'triangle'.");
        }
    }while(notAcceptable);

    double radius = 0.0;
    double base = 0.0;
    double height = 0.0;
    boolean acceptable = false;
    boolean acceptable1 = false;
    boolean acceptable2 = false;

    if(shape.equals("circle")){
        System.out.print("Enter the radius of the circle: ");

        while( !acceptable ){
        //check if the input is a double.
        if (myScanner.hasNextDouble()){
        radius = myScanner.nextDouble();
        acceptable = true;
        break;
        }
        else{
        System.out.println("ERROR: Input must be a double");
        System.out.print("Enter the radius of the circle ");
        myScanner.next();
        }
        } 

    }else{
        System.out.print("Enter the height: ");
        while( !acceptable1 ){
        //check if the input is a double.
        if (myScanner.hasNextDouble()){
        height = myScanner.nextDouble();
        acceptable = true;
        break;
        }
        else{
        System.out.println("ERROR: Input must be a double");
        System.out.print("Enter the height: ");
        myScanner.next();
        }
        }

        System.out.print("Enter the length of the base: ");
        while( !acceptable2 ){
        //check if the input is a double.
        if (myScanner.hasNextDouble()){
        base = myScanner.nextDouble();
        acceptable = true;
        break;
        }
        else{
        System.out.println("ERROR: Input must be a double");
        System.out.print("Enter the length of the base: ");
        myScanner.next();
        }
        }
    }

    if(shape=="circle"){
        circleArea(radius);
    }else if (shape=="triangle"){
        triangleArea(base,height);
    }else{
        rectangleArea(base,height);
    }


}//bracket that closes main method

    public static void circleArea(double r){
        double areaC= 3.14*r*r;
        System.out.println("The area of your circle is "+areaC);
    }

    public static void rectangleArea(double b1, double h1 ){
        double areaR= b1*h1;
        System.out.println("The area of your rectangle is "+areaR);
    }

    public static void triangleArea(double b2, double h2){
        double areaT = 0.5*b2*h2;
        System.out.println("The area of your triangle is "+areaT);
    }


}//bracket that closes class
```

Comment: Well...your triangle doesn't doesn't have `0.5` to multiply the base and height with

Comment: And where is radius set?

Comment: As a side note, you are not returning anything from that function, you are just printing it.

Comment: The absence of the 0.5 was a miss-type, I do have it in my code and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember when comparing `Strings` in Java, you need to use the `equals` method. By using `==`, you are doing a [reference comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus).

Try this:

```
if(shape.equals("circle")) {
    circleArea(radius);
}else if (shape.equals("triangle")) {
    triangleArea(base,height);
} else {
    rectangleArea(base,height);
}
```

Or, to guard against nulls and make it case insensitive, most developers will go with this:

```
if("circle".equalsIgnoreCase(shape) {
    circleArea(radius);
} else if ("triangle".equalsIgnoreCase(shape)) {
    triangleArea(base,height);
} else {
    rectangleArea(base,height);
}
```

Because you are using `==`, you always fall through the `else` case, which is calculating the rectangle.

And as others have mentioned, you probably also have errors in your calculations.

Comment: Wow this was all it took to fix it, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you actually don't multiply triangle's area by `0.5`, the code should be:

```
double area = b2*h2*0.5;
System.out.println("The area of your triangle is "+area);
```

Also check if you have correct input. Please post prove of input's correctness.